# Sending an array from a C pointer to a JS function without copying

Tags: javascript, c, emscripten

I'd like to send a data pointer to a JS function at a very high rate (in order to render it on a canvas). What is the best way to do this with Emscripten, without copying the actual data ?

Is the following correct?

```
void send(void const * data, unsigned length) {

    EM_ASM({

        var data = new Uint8Array(HEAP8.buffer, $0, $1);
        Module.send();

    }, data, length);

}
```

The issue is that it requires an Uint8Array allocation at each frame, which will not make the garbage collector very happy... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Emscripten GL implementation](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten/blob/15f9d98abd556a8f4bbf283e4d1121a66f20f0f9/src/library_gl.js#L1192), it seems that the best way to achieve what I want is [TypedArray#subarray](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/TypedArray/subarray). I wonder if it might affect the garbage collection, tho.

```
void send(void const * data, unsigned length) {

    EM_ASM({

        Module.send(HEAPU8.subarray($0, $0 + $1));

    }, data, length);

}
```